# C# Чтение и запись потока в одном классе

Tags: c#, .net

Есть ли в .net класс, который может делать и чтении и запись данных в файл?

```
using (var stream = File.Open("path", FileMode.Open))
{
    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
    {
        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Можно ли сократить этот код?
В один единственный `using`?
FileStream не подходит, так как записать/прочитать что то кроме типа byte сложновато.
Разумно ли создать свой класс, который содержит в себе `FileStream`, и `BinaryReader` и `BinaryWriter`?

Comment: Ответ зависит от того, что этот код должен делать

Comment: просто любопытно, что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: То, что умеет BinaryReader и BinaryWriter.

Comment: Я хочу записывать данные типа byte, int, string, long и тд в бинарный файл. И одновременно что то считать. Например - прочитать int и после записать что то.

Comment: Если вы хотите совместить функционал 2 классов в одном (что нарушает SRP), то вы можете написать обертку над ними с нужными вам методами

Comment: tym32167, вы про Single Responsibility Principle? Это не так критично. Я знаю несколько популярных проектов, которые про SRP, похоже, ничего не знают.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [FileStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx), все необходимые методы он имеет.

> FileStream работает только с байтами данных. Записать/прочитать не
>   байт в одну строку не получится. – HarkBack 9 минут назад

Что-то мне подсказывает, что вы ошибаетесь. В противном случае - объясните, что такое "не байт в одну строку".

```
string data = ".....";
byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(data);
fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
```

Comment: FileStream работает только с байтами данных. Записать/прочитать не байт в одну строку не получится.

Comment: @HarkBack, обновил.

Comment: Ну всмысле то что только байты можно записать. То есть нужно в ручную переводить int, string и тд в массив byte (и не допустить ошибку). При чтении та же история. BinaryWriter уже имеет готовые для записи методы.

Comment: @HarkBack, так наследуйте его, напишите обертки. Вы минусанули ответ, сказав "Записать/прочитать не байт в одну строку не получится." - а выясняется то, что получится. ;)

Comment: (это не я минусанул. я вообще не могу влиять на это)

Comment: @HarkBack, тогда прошу прощения)) 
И прошу человека, который это сделал, объяснить мне причины сего действа. Иначе так не интересно. Вроде, "Вы не правы, потому что я так решил".

Comment: "так наследуйте его". В принципе как вариант. Так и сделаю. Спасибо XD

Comment: @HarkBack, не за что, рад, что смог помочь.